# How to select second or third thead in print by css selector

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors

Is any way to select thead element based repeation in print mode like this:

```
thead:nth-of-type(1), thead:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

In Print Preview, when my tbody content is so long, my content broke to more than one page, and the thead tag repeated, now i want to set some style to first thead only

Comment: When i try to print a page, i want to set some style to first thead element only

Comment: My problem is in Print Preview, when thead tag repeated automatically,

Comment: what do you mean by `thead tag repeated automatically` ? do you have more tables than one ? can you write an example html output of your problem ?

Comment: @MihaiT But this is one table spread out over different printed pages, with the thead repeated on each page.

Comment: In Print Preview, when my tbody content is so long, my content broke to more than one page, and the thead tag repeated, now i want to set some style to first thead only.

Comment: i don't know if you can do that. there is a `@page` css rule together with ` :first` but you cannot style elements inside the page only the page itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page

Comment: I tried experimenting with JavaScript, writing `<thead style="color:red">` and then `document.querySelector('thead').style = '';` directly after in the tbody, but that works too well: it removes the style from the first printed thead too. And the one on the screen.